# Date and Time Parsing

Tags: java, plsql

I am processing a flat file,I am getting date as something like->20121210 and time as like->124040,How come I parse this and insert into database as timestamp,I am using java and pl/sql ?

Comment: Check `SimpleDateFormatter`.

Comment: I am getting both the time and date too

Comment: you should always show your efforts by posting your relevant part of code

Comment: Sure,but I am doing it on a client machine,So Cant able to copy and doesn't have a local environment to test the code,that is why no codes.Sorry

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmSS");
String fromFileDateTime = "20121210"+"T"+"124040";
Date date = format.parse(fromFileDateTime );
```

populate `fromFileDateTime` variable by combining Date,Time strings you obtained from flat file.

Comment: But what about the datestring? in parse(dateString);

Comment: not sure on that `'T'` part though, execute and then decide whether to keep it or to go "yyyyMMddHHmmSS"

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, java.text.ParseException {


    String date = "20121210 124040";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMd HHmmss");

    Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

}
```

Output:

```
Mon Dec 10 12:40:40 IST 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are getting date and time as string. So, You need `parse` method of [SimpleDateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Explore more patterns in the API.

Quoting from API:

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates
>   in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text),
>   parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmSS");
        try{
            String dateString = "20121210"+" " + "124040";
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + date);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
run:
Formatted Date: Mon Dec 10 12:40:00 IST 2012
```