# java converting date in string format to timestamp

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a date in this format: **"Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM"**  to a
 timestamp value in this format:   **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**.

example:

`String str = 'Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM'` should output: `"2013-01-14 23:59:59"`

Here is what I've tried:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string); 
System.out.println(date);
```

This outputs: `Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2010`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: And how exactly are you trying to convert?

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: String string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
 System.out.println(date); Output::Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2010

Comment: String str = 'Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM' am having string like this i need output like "2013-01-14 23:59:59"

Comment: if you add that info to the question it won't be closed and you'll get the answer

Comment: oh sorry am new to the community that why...

Comment: np just edit your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM";          
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = sdf1.parse(str);
System.out.println("Date Object:" + date);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a");
System.out.println("Formatted Date:" + sdf2.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Date Object: Fri Mar 01 16:30:00 EST 2013 

Formatted Date: 2013-03-01 16:30 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are getting date and time as Date. So, You need `format` method of [SimpleDateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Explore more patterns in the API.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
        Date currDate = new Date();
        System.out.println("Current Date: " + currDate);
        System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + sdf.format(currDate));
}
```

Output:

```
Current Date: Wed Feb 06 13:15:19 IST 2013
Formatted Date: 2013-02-06 13:15:750
```

If you have date in string format, you need to **parse** it in Date first and then format it.

Example:

```
   String str = "Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm a"); 
   Date parsedDate = sdf2.parse(str);
   System.out.println("Parsed Date: " + parsedDate);

   sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS a");
   System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + sdf2.format(parsedDate));
```

Output:

```
Parsed Date: Fri Mar 01 04:30:00 IST 2013
Formatted Date: 2013-03-01 04:30:00 AM
```

Comment: Use `parse` method if you want to format string to formatted date. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624818/date-and-time-parsing/14625030#14625030

Comment: i had String str = 'Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM' like this but above code not converting some error coming like this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers were good answers in 2013. Time is moving on, and so is the handling of time information in Java. If you can use Java 8, do yourself the favour of using the date and time classes in the new `java.time` package (also backported to Java 6 and 7 in the ThreeTen Backport):

```
    String str = "Fri Mar 1, 2013 4:30 PM";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d, uuuu h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH));
```

This produces a time without time zone of `2013-03-01T16:30`. To format it into the desired output format:

```
    System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```

This prints:

```
2013-03-01 16:30:00
```

Should your want your timestamp in UTC, you may convert from your computer’s time zone like this:

```
ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
```

Since I am in the Central European Time zone, on my computer it produces a point in time of `2013-03-01T15:30:00Z` (where `Z` signifies UTC; `Instant` objects are always printed in UTC).

Link: [ThreeTen Backport Home](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)