# How to convert String time stamp to java.sql.Timestamp?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I have time stamp in String format as "Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:56:38 GMT". So, how can convert this string time stamp into "2017-02-23 04:56:38.0" format.
I tried link [java converting date in string format to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723872/java-converting-date-in-string-format-to-timestamp) . But facing error in conversion.
My sample code is as below.

```
String str = "Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:56:38 GMT";


    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date) sdf1.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Date Object:" + date);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Formatted Date:" + sdf2.format(date));
```

Error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 23 Feb 2017 04:56:38 GMT"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Comment: [SimpleDateFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) > a | Am/pm marker | Text | PM , so you are using the AM/PM marker to parse Timezone ...

Comment: @Fildor, you are right. after change a to z in simpleDateformat it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39281606) on a duplicate Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the sdf1 format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
```

Here `z` means

```
Date or Time Component  Presentation        Examples
Time zone               General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
```

Answer (score 2):

I am aware that you have got it to work now. Please allow me to mention anyway: Your format is built-in as `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. So parsing your string is a one-liner:

```
    Instant i = OffsetDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).toInstant();
```

Since you were asking for a `java.sql.Timestamp` in your title, I was thinking that you might need this for your database? A modern JDBC driver (version 4.2 or newer) should be able to accept an `Instance` directly. If you are not that lucky, it’s still easy:

```
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(i);
```

I am using some of the classes in the `java.time` package (with subpackage `java.time.format`). The above is just a very simple example of where these are more programmer-friendly than the old classes `Timestamp` and `SimpleDateFormat` (from Java 1.0 or 1.1, I think). I keep meeting examples every time I use them (and certainly when I answer quetions on Stack Overflow about tricky bugs in using the old classes).

`java.time` is standard in Java 8. If you want to use the classes in Java 6 or 7, get them in [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).